# Search is a timeline sequence?

Tags: algorithm, search, time-series, binary-search-tree

We have a stream of inputs of the format -- {val, timestamp}. Timestamp is strictly increasing. Values are integers(32-bit). We are only interested in last n timestamp events. Eg. If n is 100 and add(400, 12) is called, we are only interested in time series [300, 400]. We also want to be able to search in the last n timestamp events.

For search if there is no value with the specific timestamp, we want to return the value of the previous timestamp(given that the previous timestamp is in the range [latestTimestamp-n, latestTimestamp]).

One way to solve this is to use binary search tree(map in C++). When adding we would add the element to the BST. So, add would have O(log n) complexity. For search, we would just do a lower_bound(in C++) search and check whether the timestamp falls in the valid range([latestTimestamp-n, latestTimestamp]). Search would also have O(log n) complexity.

I wanna know if there is an algorithm with better time complexity even at the cost of increase in space complexity ? I am more interested in improving the time complexity of search(timestamp) operation.

Comment: What is the average gap between time stamps? To put it another way, given that the timestamps we're interested in are between 300 and 400, how many timestamps would we expect to be in that range?

Comment: There is no consistency or pattern there. All that is guaranteed is that the timestamps are in strictly increasing order. Would it help if we consider n(valid timestamp range) as a constant rather than an input?

Answer (score 4):

Since every time stamp you add goes after all the preceding ones, and the timestamps you remove are always the first ones, you just need a queue that supports fast search.

If you use a dynamic array-backed queue (like ArrayDeque in Java), then adding a new entry to the end, and removing any entries from the start that it obsoletes, can be done in amortized constant time.  Search would be a simple binary search and would take O(log N).

Comment: You are right, we can do add(val, timestamp) in constant time. But is there a way to improve the time complexity of search(timestamp) operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hash table and have an average of O(1) per operation and worst case O(n). But if you care about worst case than you should use @Matt Timmermans answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to search values by timestamp and that `N` will remain stable over time (it can change, but won't affect the amortized time complexity).

First (same as @Matt Timmermans answer), you can use a very simple data structure to store the pairs `(timestamp, value)`: take an array `pairs` of size `N` and an offset `cur_pair`. To add a new element, in pseudo code:

```
pairs[cur_pair] = (timestamp, value)
cur_pair = cur_pair + 1 % N
```

This is *O(1)*.

To search a given timestamp in *O(n)*, just loop over the `pairs[cur_pair], ..., pairs[N-1], pairs[0], ..., pairs[cur_pair-1]` until you exceed the timestamp you are looking for. The result is the last value you have read before you exit the loop. (It's up to you to decide what you do when the timestamp is before the first stored timestamp or after the last stored timestamp).

As you have seen, it's possible to speed up the search with a binary search:

```
# look for timestamp t
s = cur_pair, e = (cur_pair-1) % N
loop:
    if (e-s) % N <= 1:
        return pairs[s].value

    middle = (s+e) // 2 % N # // is integer division
    if pairs[middle].timestamp > t:
        s = middle
    else:
        e = middle
```

This is *O(log N)*.

Now, you can have, under some assumptions, a seach in ***O(1)* amortized**. Before I give the assumptions, let's see the idea.

Keep the previous `pairs` array, but add a new array `timestamps` of length `M`. This array slices the time in equals time slices of a `slice` duration. You have a `cur_ts` to store the current index.  Add is now:

```
new_ts = timestamp // slice
for ts in [cur_ts + 1, ..., new_ts]: # every time slice bewteen cur+1 and new ts...
    timestamps[ts % M] = cur_pair # ...gets the value of the index in pair array.
cur_ts = new_ts % M

# and the previous add:
pairs[cur_pair] = (timestamp, value)
cur_pair = cur_pair + 1 % N
```

This is still O(1). Note that only the first timestamp in a time slice is stored.

Now, search for timestamp `t` is (I do not write the edge cases):

```
index = t // slice
s = timestamps[index] # lower bound
e = timestamps[index + 1 % M] # upper bound

# do the full lookup or the binary search here.
```

Now, why do I say this is *O(1)* amortized time complexity?

1. compute timestamp index in `timestamp` (a division modulo `M`: *O(1)*)
2. find pair index (access to an element in the array: *O(1)*)
3. find the right timestamp starting at the prevous index.

Step 3. is *O(1)* only if you can choose a `slice` value that is small enough to be sure that you will almost never have two timestamps in a slice. What "almost never" means is part the famous space-time tradeoff.

Pleast note that you have some work to do to deal with edge cases (`M` should be large enough to store `N` timestamps, etc.).